# Changing volume does move the slider, but not the audio output

Tags: c#, .net

I have a slider and a webbrowser object in my form and sliding it should change the volume, however it does move the slider as seen here: [image: Slider does move, but sound output doesn't change]

but it doesn't change the volume's actual output. This is probably because I integrated the WebBrowser object and using Windows 7. When I manually slide the slider (the one seen in the screenshot) the volume output **does** change. When playing a .wav file the volume's output **does** change, but not with the WebBrowser object.

I'm using the following code:

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="10" ValueChanged="ValueChanged"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        // Calculate the volume that's being set
        double newVolume = ushort.MaxValue * e.NewValue / 10.0;

        uint v = ((uint) newVolume) & 0xffff;
        uint vAll = v | (v << 16);

        // Set the volume
        int retVal = NativeMethods.WaveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, vAll);

        Debug.WriteLine(retVal);
    }
}

static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "waveOutSetVolume")]
    public static extern int WaveOutSetVolume(IntPtr hwo, uint dwVolume);

}
```

Comment: IE runs code in a separate process these days.  waveOutSetVolume only sets the volume for the current process.  This ought to be difficult to fix.

Comment: @HansPassant Alright, but why does manually sliding the Windows slider changes the volume? I do see the Windows slider moving (when sliding through my program) but it doesn't change the volume output (only when I slide the Windows slider (not through my program)).

Comment: @Devator.  Hi again.  I created a simple app with a browser control + the code above.  I navigated to a You Tube video.  The WPF slider and the Windows Mixer both work fine.  Can we see how you're playing a sound using the browser control?

Comment: @Phil It navigates to `http://r.gf-tec.nl/l.php?p=http://shoutcastinfo.radiostaddenhaag.com/stad.wax`. This is just a random example of a radio station, but most use Windows Media Player (the WebBrowser control is not visible either).

Comment: @Devator, ok I get the same behaviour as you with that url, but it's fine with a You Tube video. I have no idea why at the moment.

Comment: @Phil Alright, thanks. Seems it has todo with Windows Media Player then.

Comment: @Devator Just finished an answer to the regex question you deleted today (20120629). I thought the question was valid. If you still want here it is worksol.be/temp/regex.txt Let me know you got it so I can deleted this comment :)

Comment: @buckley Thanks, but a HTML parses is really the way to go =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.volume.aspx).

Then you could play your radio station like this:

```
<MediaElement LoadedBehavior="Manual" x:Name="media" />

media.Source = new Uri(@"http://shoutcastinfo.radiostaddenhaag.com/stad.wax");
media.Play();
```

And change the volume with

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="1" ValueChanged="ValueChanged"/>

private void ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    media.Volume = e.NewValue;
}
```

Both the Windows Mixer and the WPF slider now change the volume appropriately, but the values of the two are independent and don't reflect each other's' changes.

Comment: The media element isn't an option for me, it's not available for desktop applications (Windows forms) and not all radio stations are .wax, some are even flash or use their own implementation. That's why the "general" volume would be the best options.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this `uint v = ((uint)newVolume) & 0xffff` is a bit redundant, `uint v = (uint)newVolume` would return the same result.

Second of all, according to [the MSDN documentation of the waveOutSetVolume method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743874.aspx):

Most devices do not support the full 16 bits of volume-level control and will not use the least-significant bits of the requested volume setting. For example, if a device supports 4 bits of volume control, the values 0x4000, 0x4FFF, and 0x43BE will all be truncated to 0x4000. The waveOutGetVolume function returns the full 16-bit setting set with waveOutSetVolume.

Have you tried large changes?

Comment: The code does work when there is no Windows Media Player element in the WebBrowser, so it seems nothing is wrong with the code and probably is something else.

Comment: @Devator The lack of the player element could be leading to lack of an open output stream. Have you tried calling waveOutOpen?